# How to match any characters except a set of contiguous characters?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match characters all characters until pattern A0343443 (`A[0-9]+`)

input:

```
A546454 : This and that happened at C:\User\John\Documents\folder. There was an error reading 
the file
B546454 : This and that happened at C:\User\John\Documents\folder. There was an error reading the file
A595949: This other thing happened at C:\User\John\Documents\....
```

desired output:

```
A546454 : This and that happened at C:\User\John\Documents\folder. There was an error reading the file
A595949: This other thing happened at C:\User\John\Documents\....
```

Because line ending is uncertain, I want to end when I reach `A[0-9]+` or `B[0-9]+`
I tried the positive lookahead :

```
^(?=A[0-9]+)
```

but that fails at the first Capital `A`

i.e. `Alot of chocolate` causes it to stop.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Please give some sample inputs and your expected outputs.

Comment: Are you only wanting to match lines that start with `A#######` ?

Comment: Do your lines only start with `A` or `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your lines start with `A` or `B`, you can use a **Negative Lookahead**.

```
^(?!B[0-9]+).+$
```

See [`Live Demo`](http://regex101.com/r/bV9eA1)